# google maps not displayed correctly unless refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I am using JQuery mobile with the Google Map API.
The map is not displayed properly unless I refresh the page and I don't understand why.

here is my map.html file:

```
<div data-role="page" id="map-page">  
    <div data-role="content" id="canvas-map" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <script src="js/map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $canvasMap = $('#canvas-map');
        $('#canvas-map').on('pagebeforeshow', initMap());
    </script>
</div>
```

and my map.js file:

```
function initMap() {
    "use strict";
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

    var marker, map, 
        myLocation = {lat:50, lon:-80},
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLocation.lat, myLocation.lon),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.PLAN,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };

    $('#canvas-map').css("height", "200px").css("padding", "0px");
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvas-map'), mapOptions);

    /** MyPosition **/
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLocation.lat, myLocation.lon),
    });
}
```

If I navigate from another page to the above page, I get the following result:
[image: broken google maps]

And then when I refresh, I get the expected result:
[image: refreshed google maps working fine]

It is obviously not a problem with the canvas, since it is displayed (in red). Plus,if I navigate trhough the map, I can see the marker displayed at the right position.
These screenshots were made using Google Chrome, I tried with Firefox and the canvas is here completely red, no map at all.

PS: this is a simple version of my original code, but the behavior is the same.

### EDIT:

See Gajotres' answer for details, but basically, within the link to access map.html page, adding `target="_blank"` solved the issue. Note that `target="_self"` seems to work as well, strange since it is supposed to be the default value. Details on **target** [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.16).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a trick how **`google maps v3`** framework can be easily implemented with jQuery Mobile.

Lets talk about the problems here. your content div has a height and width problem, mainly because only time page dimensions can be calculated correctly is during the **pageshow** event. But even then content div will not cover full page.

Your problem can be solved with a little bit of CSS :

```
#content {
    padding: 0 !important;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0 !important; 
    left : 0 !important;     
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

Basically you are forcing your content to cover available space.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RFNPt/2/

## Final solution :

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <title>MyTitle</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div data-role="page" class="page"> 
            <div data-role="content" id="index-content">
                <div id="menu">
                    <a href="map.html" data-role="button" target="_blank">Map</a>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

#### map.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <title>MyTitle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="map-page">            
            <div data-role="content" id="content">
                <div id="canvas-map" style="height:100%"/>
            </div>      
            <style>
                #content {
                    padding: 0 !important; 
                    position : absolute !important; 
                    top : 0 !important; 
                    right : 0 !important; 
                    bottom : 40px !important;  
                    left : 0 !important;     
                }       
            </style>            
            <script type="text/javascript">         
                $(document).on('pageshow', '#map-page', function(e, data) {
                    var marker, map, 
                        myLocation = { 
                            lat: 50, 
                            lon: -80 
                        }, 
                        mapOptions = { 
                            zoom: 5, 
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.PLAN, 
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLocation.lat, myLocation.lon) 
                        }; 
                    $('#canvas-map').css("height", "200px").css("padding", "0px"); 
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvas-map'), mapOptions); 
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                        map: map, 
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLocation.lat, myLocation.lon), 
                    });     
                }); 
            </script>           
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/)** you will find much more information regarding this topic plus examples.

Comment: Using your working example, I managed to reproduce the error. You can have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/leochab/MfhSX/

Comment: Easily fixable, map must be initialized on correct page, in your case, because map is part of a index2 page it must be initialized during the index2 pageinit event. http://jsfiddle.net/UbhdS/1/ This is the only difference between your and my code.

Comment: Or there's one more solution, I will also add it to my answer.

Comment: Note that on my local machine I have 2 seperates files: the `index.html` file with a link to the `map.html` file where I load the map. I moved all the code (`initMap()`) from the `map.js` to `map.html`, but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: If possible can you mail me those 2 files and I will fix it in few minutes. You can find my mail in my profile. If not tell me and I will try to simulate it also in 2 separate files.

Comment: Fixed files mailed back to you. I have forgot to mention I have tested them on FF and Chrome alike.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add following code...

```
$('#canvas-map').on('pageshow', function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(canvas-map, "resize");
});
```

this will fire resize event and reload the map on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: The action of **drawing the map** should be performed **after the page loads**, that is when the page has actual values for width and height and you can initialize it as follows:

```
var map; //declared as global so you can access the map object and add markers dynamically 
$("#canvas-map").on( "pageshow", function() {
    var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(53.6721226, -10.547924),
            zoom:13,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
});
```

**No refresh needed**